# Multiple stays in EU not longer than 90 days each time?

Tags: schengen

I have an EU-passport and my husband a UK passport;

1. Am I right in assuming he has freedom of movement when travelling with me?
2. We live in the UK and have a home in Spain. We like to stay 2 months at a time, are we allowed to come and go whenever we want, for instance May-June (2 months), September-October (2 months), January-February(2 months) etc, without having to count the 90 days within 180 days?
3. As each stay doesn't exceed the maximum 90 days, does this mean he doesn't have to apply for a residence permit as we are not residents, only stay part-time?

Answer (score 13):

> Am I right in assuming he has freedom of movement when travelling with me?

If you are travelling to an EU member state that **is not** the state you are a citizen of, freedom of movement applies to him too.

> **Beneficiaries**
>
> 1. This Directive shall apply to all Union citizens who move to or reside in a Member State **other than that of which they are a national**, and to their family members as defined in point 2 of Article 2 who accompany or join them.
>
> *[ ... ]*
>
> **Right of residence for up to three months**
>
> 1. Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of up to three months **without any conditions or any formalities** other than the requirement to hold a valid identity card or passport.
> 2. The provisions of paragraph 1 **shall also apply to family members** in possession of a valid passport who are not nationals of a Member State, **accompanying or joining the Union citizen**.

[Directive 2004/58/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32004L0038R%2801%29)

> We live in the UK and have a home in Spain. We like to stay 2 months at a time, are we allowed to come and go whenever we want, for instance May-June (2 months), September-October (2 months), January-February(2 months) etc, without having to count the 90 days within 180 days?

**If you are not a Spanish citizen**, his Schengen clock doesn't run when travelling with you. Just make sure to carry proof of relationship.

> As each stay doesn't exceed the maximum 90 days, does this mean he doesn't have to apply for a residence permit as we are not residents, only stay part-time?

You won't need to apply for a residence permit **but** make sure to understand the tax implications if you are in Spain for more than a 183 days in a given year.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, this is very helpful.

Comment: Can I ask another question, when you say given year, does the year start Jan-Dec or when  we were last there or how far back do we need to count, would it be a year from when we next go into Spain for example if we go in May, do we start from May the year before?

Comment: These rules only tend to apply if you're going to a country that *isn't* the one the EU national is a citizen of. For example, if a non-EU citizen travels to Denmark with a Danish citizen, normal immigration rules apply, but if you travel to Germany, then the above rule (no 90-in-180 limit) applies.

**The start of the directive states:** "This Directive shall apply to all Union citizens who move to or reside in a Member State other than that of which they are a national, and to their family members as defined in point 2 of Article 2 who accompany or join them."